# How to configure Synaptics TrackPoint/UltraNav for specific applications?

Tags: google-chrome, thinkpad, trackpoint

I have a ThinkPad X61, and I'd like to configure sensitivity of the Synaptics pointing stick scrolling feature on a per-application basis.  I did this about 4 years ago on my ThinkPad T41, using a configuration file - but I can no longer find any info on this configuration file, and there are no configuration files under C:\Program Files\Synaptics.

The pointing stick is usually known as TrackPoint or UltraNav in IBM material.

Specifically, I'm trying to reduce scrolling sensitivity in Google Chrome on a Windows 7 64-bit X61 ThinkPad.

Comment: I need that too, with thinkpad UltraNav middle button scrolling, on Google Chrome it scrolls too many lines making it unusable.

Comment: I don't personally use the TrackPoint anymore, but there are some suggestions here worth a try: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/XGyRw-smbz8